# Calculate Centroid Coordinate for a List of Lat/Long Coordinates using Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Column_1 with index value and Column_2 with list of coordinates.

Input:

| Column_1 [String] | Column_2 Array[String] |
| --- | --- |
| A | [(40.7128,-74.0060), (34.0522, -118.2437), (51.5074, -0.1278), (-33.8651, 151.2099)] |
| B | [(52.5200, 13.4050), (48.8566, 2.3522), (41.9028, 12.4964), (55.6761, 12.5683)] |

I want to calculate Centroid for the list of coordinates in Column_2.

Output:

| Column_1 [String] | Column_2 Array[String] | Centroid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | [(40.7128,-74.0060), (34.0522, -118.2437), (51.5074, -0.1278), (-33.8651, 151.2099)] | [48.3518, -10.0424] |
| B | [(52.5200, 13.4050), (48.8566, 2.3522), (41.9028, 12.4964), (55.6761, 12.5683)] | [49.739375, 10.455475] |

Comment: so u need to get the middle element of the array?

Comment: No, the centroid of all the 3 coordinates.

Comment: But that's not a centroid. A centroid of an object is the point that is nearest to all surface points of the object. Here you are just selecting either the middle item of the array or the coordinate that is mostly centered on the x-positive,y-positive quadrant of the coordinate system you are using.

Comment: It would help if you provided more context. Column_2 seems to be a line. Do you want to know the point in the array that is closest to the center of the line?

Comment: And does the array always features three points only? And all come pre-sorted as in your examples?

Comment: I have updated the input and output coordinates with the relevant information